# My ListView (of my ViewFilipper) fills the parent and buttons on the bottom get hidden

Tags: android, listview, viewflipper

Hi and thanks for your help!

This is my desired result:

[image]

This is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>

<include
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/filelist" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

where filelist.xml is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/scanning" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/list_margin"
        android:background="?attr/listBackground" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/this_folder_is_empty"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is what I get instead

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your parent `ViewGroup` (your root node in the layout file) a `RelativeLayout` and then specify `android:layout_above="@id/THE_BUTTON_CONTAINER` on the `LinearLayout` that holds the list.

The system will then ignore all intents of the list to make itself larger.

`android:layout_above` and `android:layout_below` are very handy methods when it comes to placing containers of which you don't know the size yet and I use them frequently. An example as follows:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/myMenuBar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/myStatusBar" >
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

This might work.

Inside filelist.xml change

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >
```

To

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add include tag in linear layout like this -:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/filelist" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

This may help you.I dont know whether this is a right approach but for now may be the solution for you.