# My ListView (of my ViewFilipper) hides buttons at the bottom

Tags: android

I try again... [My ListView (of my ViewFilipper) fills the parent and buttons on the bottom get hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424117/my-listview-of-my-viewfilipper-fills-the-parent-and-buttons-on-the-bottom-get/18425484?noredirect=1#18425484)

This is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutinclude"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ViewFlipper

        android:id="@+id/flipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inAnimation="@anim/fade_in"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:outAnimation="@anim/fade_out" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indeterminate="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/scanning" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/list_margin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/listBackground"
                android:fastScrollEnabled="true" >
            </ListView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@android:id/empty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/this_folder_is_empty"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my desired result:

[image]

This is what I get instead:

[image]

Comment: @avalancha it is similar, not the same...please do not close this question

Comment: Make your parent ViewGroup (your root node) a RelativeLayout and specify `android:layout_above="@id/THE_BUTTON_CONTAINER` on the LinearLayout that holds the list. The system will then ignore all intents of the list to make itself larger

Comment: @avalancha Thank you very very much!! 1 that did the trick. If you post an answer I will happy to accept it!!! :-)))

Comment: Very glad to help :) I posted the answer below your original thread, thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutinclude"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/flipper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inAnimation="@anim/fade_in"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:outAnimation="@anim/fade_out">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <ProgressBar
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:indeterminate="true"/>

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/scanning"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center">

                <ListView
                        android:id="@android:id/list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_margin"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/list_margin"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="?attr/listBackground"
                        android:fastScrollEnabled="true">
                </ListView>

                <TextView
                        android:id="@android:id/empty"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/this_folder_is_empty"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ViewFlipper>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you very much, avalancha solved the problem. Thank you anyway!!!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the weight in the last LinearLayout

Comment: thank you very much, avalancha solved the problem. Thank you anyway!!!